# Can Intersection observer be used to calculate/trigger at specific offset top of target?

Tags: javascript, intersection-observer

TL,DR:

I don't care how much of the target container is visible, I just want to know when the target container reaches a specific offset from top of the viewport (window). Should I stick with the good old scroll event or can this be done with Intersection observer?

Long story:

For a project I need to create a vertical scrolling parallax effect (as seen on [this page](https://www.shopskin.co.uk/collections/spots/products/triple-microdermabrasion-face-polish), when viewed on large screens).

The parallax animation needs to detect when the target container reaches a specific offset from top of the viewport. And it needs to know the scroll direction.

I've found this question that explains how the [visibilty percentage can be used to determine the scoll direction](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46478202/how-do-i-know-the-intersectionobserver-scroll-direction), which solves my 2nd problem.

So my question is: Can I use Intersection observer to trigger a callback when my target container reaches a specific offset from top of the viewport?

In pseudo-code, I'd need something like this:

```
var observer = new IntersectionObserver(offsetReached, {root: null});

function offsetReached(entries, observer) {
  entries.forEach(entry => {
    if (entry.offsetFromTop == '200px') {
      entry.target.classList.add('container--fixed');
    }
  });
}

observer.observe('.container');
```

Answer (score 3):

Use the `rootMargin` option on the `IntersectionObserver`:

```
var observer = new IntersectionObserver(offsetReached, {rootMargin: '-200px'});
```

> Each side of the rectangle represented by rootMargin is added to the corresponding side in the root element's bounding box before the intersection test is performed. ([MDN Web Docs: Intersection)Observer.rootMargin)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/IntersectionObserver/rootMargin#browser_compatibility)

Answer (score 1):

Intersectionobserver's purpose is to detect when a portion of element becomes visible, if you want to watch for `offSet`the best option is to use the old fashioned `scroll` event and `getBoundingClientRect()` on the element you need to watch on.